Why datachanged is not emmited?
In my model class I have
class OnCallDutyList(QAbstractListModel):
    ...
    def addEvent(self, event):
        index = QModelIndex()
        self.beginInsertRows(index, self.rowCount(index), self.rowCount(index))
        self._events.append(event)
        self._events.sort(key=lambda x: x["start"], reverse=False)
        self.endInsertRows()

Then connecting the event in parent class
self.ocdModel.dataChanged.connect(lambda: self.saveOCD())

However, saveOCD never fires. I was thinking endInsertRows() should emit the event.
What is the right event for listening to add/remove events in QAbstractListModel?

The dataChanged documentation explains it quite clearly: "This signal is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes". Obviously, a new row does not change an item, since that item didn't exist before. If you check the documentation more carefully, you'll see that the "Signals" section also lists the rowsInserted signal.
